# automated copying of select columns to new worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Am fairly new to excel and was wondering if there is an easier way to do a routine cut copy paste I do. I have a worksheet that has a long list of columns which looks like following:

```
Name     Age    Occupation    Major    WorkEx     Position.....
```

I want the macro to copy some predetermined columns from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2 i.e each time I copy raw data into worksheet 1 worksheet 2 should be auto-populated with the selected columns. In this case for example,if I paste the aforementioned columns into worksheet 1, then Name, Major and Position should automatically be copied to worksheet 2.

A point to note is that the raw data is not always in order as shown above. I believe the key is to locate/find the header and then copy the entire column on to worksheet 2 on specific columns.

In this case worksheet 2 will always have Col 8-10 and Col 16 as blank.

Would anyone be able to help me with this issue? Let me know if any additional details are necessary.

Comment: Do you want like a macro button or how would you run the macro?

Comment: @Niclas a Macro Button would be great. All I need is the macro to be able to copy the columns which will be hard coded.

Comment: @Niclas I have added more details on end of para 2 and para 3 to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. Just replace test1 with your column names, etc.
Remember to add the column number instead of targetCol as you want to hardcode it. I used the range object to copy data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCode()

'Declaring the variable lColumn as long to store the last Column number
Dim lColumn As Long
'Declaring the variable iCntr as long to use in the For loop
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long, targetCol As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet, targetWks As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim fCol As String

' Set wks so it is the activesheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set targetWks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lastCol = wks.Cells(1, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


'Assigning the last Column value to the variable lColumn
lColumn = lastCol

'Using for loop
For iCntr = lColumn To 1 Step -1

    If LCase(wks.Cells(1, iCntr)) Like LCase("Test1") Then
        ' Find column letter
        fCol = GetColumnLetter(iCntr)
        lastRow = wks.Range(fCol & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Declare range object
        Set rng = wks.Range(fCol & "2:" & fCol & lastRow)

        ' Use Range object to copy data
        rng.Copy _
        Destination:=targetWks.Cells(1, targetCol) ' Replace targetCol with number of column (A=1, B=2, etc.)
    End If

    If LCase(wks.Cells(1, iCntr)) Like LCase("Test2") Then
        ' Find column letter
        fCol = GetColumnLetter(iCntr)
        lastRow = wks.Range(fCol & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Declare range object
        Set rng = wks.Range(fCol & "2:" & fCol & lastRow)

        ' Use Range object to copy data
        rng.Copy _
        Destination:=targetWks.Cells(1, targetCol) ' Replace targetCol with number of column (A=1, B=2, etc.)
    End If

    If LCase(wks.Cells(1, iCntr)) Like LCase("Test") Then
        ' Find column letter
        fCol = GetColumnLetter(iCntr)
        lastRow = wks.Range(fCol & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Declare range object
        Set rng = wks.Range(fCol & "2:" & fCol & lastRow)

        ' Use Range object to copy data
        rng.Copy _
        Destination:=targetWks.Cells(1, targetCol) ' Replace targetCol with number of column (A=1, B=2, etc.)
    End If

    ' etc etc
Next

End Sub

Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: it didn't copy anything on Sheet2. After running the macro, Sheet2 is still empty. I replaced all the Tests with actual column names.

Comment: I ran it again. It seems to work however, the columns are being copied at random locations. Mine is at Column CL, then at CC and AX. Instead of copying the cells to Colum A, B,C..and so on.

Comment: Hmm weird. It should copy the column from Sheet1 to Sheet2, starting with Column A and so on. Do you have any data in Sheet2?

Comment: But you can just hardcode where the columns are copied to. So if you want Occupation to always be in Column D, Age in Column B, etc. it is possible

Comment: would you be able to provide an example using the code above? Let's say for example Test1 should be copied on Column A. I can modify the code for the remainder. Thank you for helping me out with this.

Comment: just edit targetcol to the number of the column. So A = 1, B = 2 etc

Comment: That worked! One minor thing, would it be possible to make the columns be copied from row 2 instead of row 1 so that headers are not included?

Comment: So you don't want the whole column now? Just the rows from 2 to lastrow?

Comment: yes. That is correct. I apologise for forgetting that last detail.

Comment: Should work now :-) Just remember to follow the instructions.